# Trying to validate username and password in javascript but not getting alert and desired output

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

please check the code

```js
function validate() {

  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd");
  if (name == null || name == "") {
    alert("Name can't be blank");
    return false;
  } else if (pwd.length < 6) {
    alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  username: <input type="text" id="name"></input>
  <br>
  password: <input type="password" id="pwd"></input>
  <br>
  <button onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you arent checking the input's value, like `name==""` you have to access the `value` property, eg `name.value=""`

Comment: Submitting the form reloads the page (stupid default IMO). You need to prevent the default behaviour with `function validate(event) { event.preventDefault(); ..... `

Answer (score 4):

```js
function validate() {

  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
  if (name === null || name === "") {
    alert("Name can't be blank");
    return false;
  } else if (pwd.length < 6) {
    alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  username: <input type="text" id="name"></input>
  <br>
  password: <input type="password" id="pwd"></input>
  <br>
  <button onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier way to do what you are trying to do. You can use the native properties of `form` to your advantage:

```html
<form>
  Username: <input type="text" minlength="2" required>
  <br> Password: <input type="password" minlength="6" required>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. HTML elements should be before javascript, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  username: <input type="text" id="name"></input>
  <br>
  password: <input type="password" id="pwd"></input>
  <br>
  <button onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function validate() {

  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
  if (name == null || name == "") {
    alert("Name can't be blank");
    return false;
  } else if (pwd.length < 6) {
    alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");
    return false;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

2. You haven't provided the full code, so we can't really help you. As far as i can see you didn't make the alert for succesful validation.
3. You need to get the value, so you need to add .value to the getElement functions.